# How to add a namespace when parsing string to Xelement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-namespaces, xelement

I'm looking to set a namespace to the `Xelement` below. How to achieve it?

```
string Namespace = "http://mynamespace";
string defaultXml = "<ReferResult><Text> Testing Referred</Text></ReferResult>"

Xelement myXml = XElement.Parse(defaultXml);

// How to add the name space to myXml?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XNamespace Namespace = "http://mynamespace";
string defaultXml = "<ReferResult><Text> Testing Referred</Text></ReferResult>";

XElement myXml = XElement.Parse(defaultXml);
myXml.Name = Namespace + myXml.Name.LocalName;

//If you want the children to have the same namespace, use the following.
//If you want only the parent to have the namespace, omit the code bellow 
foreach(var element in myXml.Descendants()){
    element.Name = Namespace + element.Name.LocalName;
}

//Output:
//<ReferResult xmlns="http://mynamespace">
//    <Text> Testing Referred</Text>
//</ReferResult>
```

Edit: As OP's requested in the comments, to remove the namespaces, just use the same code, but omiting the namespace part:

```
myXml.Name = myXml.Name.LocalName;
foreach(var element in myXml.Descendants()){
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Magnetron, thanks for that. Will it be possible for you to also write how to just remove all namespace including an empty one in the above example?

Comment: @rohitsingh An "empty" namespace means the default one. It's not possible to remove that. Can you post an example of what you mean? The output you're getting and the desired one?

Comment: @rohitsingh anyway, I posted a code to remove namespaces.

Comment: My ultimate objective is to attach this little piece of xml without any namespace into another xml(which have all the namespaces) and since removing namepaces was not achievable for me, I thought to copy the namespace from the parent xml into this xml. But if I can achieve the ultimate objective that would be awesome

Comment: @rohitsingh Well, if mean that you don't want the "xmlns..." to be _displayed_ when you convert the xml to string, then what you need to do is make sure that the element namespace matches its parent's, like the output I posted, `Text` has the same namespace as `ReferResult` so it's not displayed. But if you convert to string only the `Text` node, the namespace will be showed.